Join LinqKit.PredicateBuilder across different Tables C#
I am trying to use LinqKit.PredicateBuilder to return if I should display a certain food drink item.
My setup is, I have a FoodDrinkType table, FoodDrinkLink table, Enquiry table, EnquiryVenue table.
In my FoodDrinkLink table I have a json list of Entities which basically means if they all exist then display the FoodDrink Item. For example I only want to show the FoodDrink item for a specific company in a specific country.
Here is a look at the data.

EntityId 7 and 14 relate to a company id and a country code.
In my code I have the following
foreach (var type in foodGroup.FoodDrinkTypes.Where(ft => ft.Online == true).OrderBy(f => f.SortOrder))
{
    var pred = LinqKit.PredicateBuilder.New<FoodDrinkType>(x => x.FoodDrinkTypeId == type.FoodDrinkTypeId);
    // this is link
    foreach (var link in type.FoodDrinkTypeLinks)
    {
        var pred2 = LinqKit.PredicateBuilder.New<FoodDrinkTypeLink>(x => x.FoodDrinkTypeId == type.FoodDrinkTypeId);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(link.LinkData))
        {
            var predList = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EntityModel>(link.LinkData);
            var pred3 = LinqKit.PredicateBuilder.New<Data.Models.Enquiry>();

            foreach (var item in predList.Entities)
            {                                                    
                switch (item.EntityId)
                {
                    case (int)ModelsEngine.Entity.Company:
                        pred3 = pred3.And(x => x.CompanyId == item.EntityRecordId);
                        break;
                    case (int)ModelsEngine.Entity.VenueFolder:
                        pred3 = pred3.And(x => x.EnquiriesVenues.Select(ev => ev.FkVenueNavigation.VenueFolderId).Contains(item.EntityRecordId));
                        break;

                }
                pred2 = pred2.Or(pred3);
                pred = pred.And(pred2);
            }
        }                                            
        var typeFound = foodGroup.FoodDrinkTypes.AsQueryable().Where(pred).ToList();

I am getting an error trying to join on the predicates but I need to use 3 different predicates in order to query against the different tables.
Is it possible to join them or what is the best approach?

Why is LinqKit used at all? There are no tables in the question's code, only data already loaded in memory. LinkData itself is so regular it should be stored in a proper table and indexed so it can be queried without loading the entire table in memory
